# Merge two columns from multiple panda series dataframes based on string matching from two columns with different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns

I need to merge two columns from a pandas series dataframe together on the last 4 digits of the first column `pack_number`.
I currently have 2 dataframes with a different number of columns.

So far, I thought about extracting the last 4 digits of the `ROOT_VIN` but I'm not sure how to proceed with column matching and merging these tables together.

Ideally, I'd like to merge the dataframe including `pack_number` (which includes 6 other columns with different values) into the dataframe including `ROOT_VIN` which also has other columns with different lengths. The goal is to include the `pack_number` and match it with its `ROOT_VIN`.

After merging, i now have 108k rows (matching the 108k rows for df2) and many of the rows are duplicated because df1 only had 451 rows.

Comment: if you extracted the last 4 digits of the ROOT_VIN in a new column named "pack_number", then you can use pandas merge

`df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on="pack_number")`

Comment: Last four values can be extracted and converted by doing: `df.ROOT_VIN.str[-4:].astype(int)`

Comment: @AlbertoHanna thank you! now i have a df3 but it is the same length as my ROOT_VIN table which had 108k columns and my other table it merged with had only 451 columns and so now there are many duplicates. How do I remove the duplicate columns?

Comment: presumably rows, not columns? I suspect you want to create a new temporary column `.astype("string")` to compare against `pack_number` (which looks like a string to me given the leading `0`s) and then drop the temp column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right then you have 2 data frames with a lot of columns.

```py
# df1 # pack_number Table
# df2 # ROOT_VIN Table

# @BeRT2me solution
df2['pack_number'] = df2['ROOT_VIN'].str[-4:]

# joining the 2 dataframes
# we add '_remove' to the duplicate columns names
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='pack_number', suffixes=('', '_remove'))

# remove the columns that end with '_remove'
df3.drop(
    [col_name for col_name in df_3.columns if '_remove' in col_name],
    axis=1, inplace=True
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant that I have 108k rows, not columns. and so now, I have the correct columns and the root_vin and _pack numbers have been correctly matched, but now I have many duplicate rows (I am assuming to match the df1 which had only 451 rows to the df2 which had 108k rows) see my edit above

Comment: `df3.drop_duplicates(inplace=True, ignore_index=True)`

or 

`df3.drop_duplicates('pack_number', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: I noticed after using that code, i tried saving the results into a new data frame as a final_merged_df but nothing shows up. will the drop_duplicates cause the df3 to automatically update the df without needing to save it in a new df name?

Comment: @ashleybee yes it's because i used `inplace=True` to change the df3 itself